# Mongoengine geospatial search

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, pymongo, mongoengine

Has anyone used geospatial searching with mongengine? I can't seem to get it to work!
What is the format of the data that has to go in the GeoPointField?

How should i format it? 
I can't find anything about the formating in the documentation!

Comment: Please mark answer as correct - it will help others when googling.

Comment: sorry, i was on vacation, fixed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can you post what you are trying to do??

Point data must be stored in a field with key

`"loc":{"lon":51.10682735591432, "lat":-114.11773681640625}`
or

`loc: [22.23432, 21.23212]`

With mongoengine there is support for a geopoint field

```
Class Location:
  point = GeoPointField()

new_location = Location(point=[21.1232,23.23432])
new_location.save()
```

something like above should work.

> class GeoPointField(db_field=None, name=None,
>   required=False, default=None, unique=False, unique_with=None,
>   primary_key=False, validation=None, choices=None, verbose_name=None,
>   help_text=None):
>
> A list storing a latitude and longitude.
>
> New in version 0.4.

http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.GeoPointField

Comment: any ideas how to query with mongoengine? mongodb provides things like: `db.places.find( { loc : { $near : [50,50] } } ).limit(20)` but i can find it in the mongoengine doc

Comment: Note that GeoPointField is now deprecated in favor of [PointField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.PointField).

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in the [mongoengine docs](http://mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=geo#query-operators):

> There are a few special operators for performing geographical queries,
>   that may used with GeoPointFields:
>
> `within_distance` – provide a list containing a point and a maximum distance (e.g. [(41.342, -87.653), 5])
>
> `within_spherical_distance` – Same as above but using the spherical geo model (e.g. [(41.342, -87.653), 5/earth_radius])
>
> `near` – order the documents by how close they are to a given point near_sphere – Same as above but using the spherical geo model
>
> `within_box` – filter documents to those within a given bounding box (e.g. [(35.0, -125.0), (40.0, -100.0)])
>
> `within_polygon` – filter documents to those within a given polygon (e.g. [(41.91,-87.69), (41.92,-87.68), (41.91,-87.65), (41.89,-87.65)]). .. note:: Requires Mongo Server 2.0